# Does $\mathbb{Q}$ have the finite-closed topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of all rational numbers with the usual topology

Does $\mathbb{Q}$ have the finite-closed topology?

My attempt :  I think yes

Finite - closed topology mean cofinite topology .we know that in the cofinite topology-$ (\mathbb{R} , T)$, the only closed sets are the finite ones, and $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

similary we can said  that in $(\mathbb{Q} , T)$ where T= cofinite Topology ,the only closed sets are the finite ones, and $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.

Is its true ?

Comment: **Any** set has the cofinite topology. The correct question would be: whether this topology on $\mathbb Q$ is the same as usual topology, to which the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{1,\frac 1 2 ,\frac  1 3...\}\cup \{0\}$ is an infinite closed set in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: thanks u sir @Kavi rama  but im confused why u take  $\{1,\frac 1 2 ,\frac  1 3...\}\cup \{0\}$  Here im talking about cofinite topology

Comment: Are asking if the only closed sets are finite sets and the whole space. I have shown that this is not the  case by producing an infinite proper subset which is closed.  @jasmine

Comment: okss thanks u sir